# Clarification on multivariate regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, multivariate-regression

In (what I call) standard regression, we have a problem of the form $y=f(a,b,c,d)$. Is it correct to say that multivariate regression is the problem of the form $g(x,y,z)=f(a,b,c,d)$?

In case this is correct, does it mean $a, b, c$ and $d$ are vectors as opposed to scalars seen in the standard regression case? Or are they scalars as well?

Comment: Have you made an attempt to look up any references to solve this issue?

Comment: Of course I have. I came here so I could get a plain English solution. There are millions of sophisticated descriptions of the term--I think users here can benefit from a toned down solution such as the one I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a reference to help you distinguish between multiple (aka "standard") regression and multivariate regression.

*Multivariate or Multivariable Regression?*

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3518362/

Comment: From this, it seems multivariate regression is of the form: g(x,y,z)=f(a)? Not clear to me. Seems like they suggest multivariate regression must necessarily have one independent variable?